# How to return a value computed by overriding method from a subclass to it's base class method in python

Tags: python, overriding

I have a base class like this:

```
class base(object):
    name = ""
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.user =user
    def context(self,value):
        return {}
```

Instead of this i created an another subclass and override this above "context" method:

```
class override(base):
    name = "New class"
    def context(self, value):
        a = []
        a = "hello","b"
        return a
```

I want to create a plugins, all they have are different definitions (different value of list will return) for context method. So i want to do this by putting override functionality.

When i call this `base.context` function from an another file. Following things should be happen:

1. The list i.e `"a"` (in override context method) should return it's value to base context method first.
2. After getting a value from `override.context` method, base.context will return that value to from where it's called after making some changes into it.

But, When i call this `base.description` method it will return a value directly from `override.description` method. So i am not able to make that changes into it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things in you question are a little confusing, but I think that what you want is something like this example (python2.7):

```
class base(object):
    name = ""

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.user =user

    def context(self, value):
        return [value]


class override(base):
    name = "override"

    def context(self, value):
        base_context = super(override, self).context(value)
        a = ["hello", "a"] + base_context

    def description(self):
        return "override description"
```

The you can do the following:

```
>>> a = override()
>>> override.context("value")
["hello", "a", "value"]
>>> override.description()
"override description"
```

However, calling these methods on `base` gives different results:

```
>>> a = base()
>>> a.context("value")
["value"]
>>> base.description()
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
AttributeError: 'base' has no attribute 'description'
```

Its not entirely clear if this is what you want though, because you refer to `base.context` getting a value from `override.context`, whereas it normally happens the other way around. The same goes for `override.description`.  If you really want `base.context` to get a value from `override.context` this can be done through `base.__subclasses__()`, but you would have to deal with all subclasses of `base`, and this sort of usage is extremely uncommon (and usually undesirable).

Answer (score 2):

Use `super(override, self).context(value)` to get `context` from `base` class.

But you example is a bit confusing because:

1) `base.context` returns dict

2) variable `a` in `override.context` is set to list, then to tuple, so `override.context` returns tuple